# Failed patching both manually and with Git in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: version-control

I am very new to both Patches and Ubuntu and [I try to run this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2635832) which fixes RTL problems for [Admin_Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module (8.x-1.11).

I've downloaded the patch file and putted it in the module's folder.

When I tried to run it manually in the terminal i didn't succeed:

[image]

Later, similar situation occurred with Git:

[image]

Where my commands accurate? What can cause it to fail? For the creator of this patch it did work... Please give me a clue or any advice you can how to solve it... Is there even anything I could do in my end?

Comment: in your git apply you forgot the **-v** so it's  `git apply -v [patchname.patch]`

Comment: Still the same problem: Patches do not apply... I guess I should strip away manually each css part and put it in admin_toolbar.css ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patch you have doesn't apply to the version of the module you have.

You either need to get a version of the module that the patch applies to, or look for/create a patch that applies cleanly to the version of the module you have installed.

Might be worth checking the patch and target files manually, the patch may well have been applied and just not have fixed the problem in the way you were expecting. I can't tell what order you've run commands in/what you've done to clean up after each and so on so it's just a guess, but the "Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!" message suggests the patch has already been applied at some point.

Comment: I know saw the patch is for version 8.x-1.x-dev, while I downloaded version 8.x-1.11 of the module... This might be the cause (?)... Even after clearing cache the problems stays the same so likely it is a version accordance problem...

Comment: BTW Clive, when I enter the patch file itself in the following link it is full of strange diff symbols I never knew before (Not only -- or ++ but other symbols)... Can I somehow strip away the diff and keep only the css changes so I would change the style.css manually and that's it? 
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/%5BAdd_rtl_support%5D-%5B2635832%5D-%5B1%5D.patch

Comment: It might be, I don't know - best to ask the module maintainer/patch creator those sorts of questions, they're the best people to know what version the code they wrote applies to. Yes you can manually apply the changes if you're comfortable reading/stripping out the relevant changes from the diff

Comment: Thank you Clive for your detailing enhanced me to do so And manually digging out the positive parts of the diff and pasting them in admin_toolbar.css indeed worked! :)